# Region inside a convex polygon

Tags: matlab

Is there a boolean function in MATLAB that gives whether a certain point in the `(x,y)` plane is insider a convex polygon given its vertices? For example, to check if a point `(a,b)` is inside the square with vertices (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), and (-1, 0), we ask MATLAB to check the condition `abs(a) + abs(b) < 1`. However, if we had a function that could instead take the vertices of a polygon and check if a point is inside it, it would be easy to generalize this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matlab function `inpolygon` does exactly what you want. In addition the function tells you which points are on the frontier of the polygon.

Please refer to the [matlab documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html).

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called [`inpolygon`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) that does exactly that.